# Lua: How is ambiguity between local and global variable labels resolved?

Tags: lua

Can anyone explain how Lua resolves such ambiguity?
I can define a global `x = 10` and then execute `local x = x`. 
<strike>It is not clear from the documentation how such a situation is handled by the interpreter.</strike> Edit: It is clear, I was looking in the wrong section. Dont cry.

From observation it seems that from there on within the block succeeding the local assignment, the label `x` will be assumed to refer to the local.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation explains this clearly.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.6)

An identifier is always checked against locals first, starting with the inner-most available scope. If it doesn't refer to a local variable that is visible, then it refers to a global variable.

As for `local x = x`, a local variable's scope starts *after* the evaluation of all the expressions that evaluate it. So first `x` is evaluated (using the existing visibility), which results in the value of `x`. Then this value is set into a newly-defined local variable called `x`.

Comment: You could have edited my question rather than down vote. It's not exactly worthless content. Thanks for the answer anyway.